# Creating a List<string> off of one of List<Object>'s string properties

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

So I have a list of Car objects.

```
List<Car> cars = GetCars();
```

I want to create a list of strings that come from the Car.Name string property.

I could do this:

```
List<string> carNames = new List<string>();
foreach(Car car in cars)
{
    carNames.Add(car.Name);
}
```

Is there a more fancy way to do this? Can you do this using LINQ?

Comment: Yes try `cars.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();` You should have atleast googled it first before coming here.

Comment: this may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786770/linq-get-distinct-values-and-fill-list I personally think what you have there is fine, nice and readable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var carNames = cars.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like a query expression syntax following works too:

```
var carNames = 
  (from c in cars
   select c.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: But.. Its not Lambda-expression. This is query-syntax, which will be converted by compiler to fluent-syntax which contains lambda-expressions.

Comment: You mean if you DON'T like lambda?

Comment: I meant Query syntax whereas the other answers are using method syntax. Both work.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Car> cars = GetCars();
List<string> carNames = cars.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score -3):

var carNames = cars.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();

Comment: This will return only First element of car names. Or Default.